# How do you set variables NORMALLY after using setlocal?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple batch file ("javapath.bat") to add the Java compiler to the path when I need it so it won't be on the path all the time. I also want be able to do something like `@call javapath.bat` in other build scripts so the path can be added automatically when needed. Since those will be run repeatedly during the edit-save-compile-run grind, that means that javapath.bat needs to check if Java is already on the path and not readd it if it is, because apparently Microsoft thinks it's a good idea to let the path variable have lots of silly duplicates.

So to detect if it needs to be added I use `setlocal` to enable "command extensions" so I can use the environment variable string substitution thing. That ugliness works fine.

Then I use `endlocal` so I can actually set the enviroment variables without the changes being reverted at the end of the script. That's not working. Or, it certainly stops the variable changes being reverted, but it's not normal: it completely stops them from being *visible* locally, but they are still visible afterwards.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
if "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" (
    endlocal
    set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant
    set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
    path %ANT_HOME%\bin;%path%
    path %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%
)
```

After the above, ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME are properly set. But the only change to PATH is that "\bin;" has been prepended to it, because none of the variables set during the script seem to be visible until afterwards (so ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME are blank, and the first change to PATH is forgotten). Therefore, running it **twice** adds Java to the path okay, and not Ant. I could hardcode the paths twice but this behavior is so bizarre and ridiculous and I've been stuck on it for an hour.

Edit: Adding `enabledelayedexpansion` had no effect either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, extensions should already be enabled except under rather extraordinary circumstances. All you need is to eliminate your SETLOCAL and restructure your IF a bit so that it exits the script if the PATH is already set.

```
@echo off
if not "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" exit /b
set "ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
path %ANT_HOME%\bin;%path%
path %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%
```

If you really need to enable extensions, then

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions
if not "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" exit /b
endlocal
set "ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
path %ANT_HOME%\bin;%path%
path %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%
```

If your script has additional work to do, then

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions
if not "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" goto :skip
endlocal
set "ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
path %ANT_HOME%\bin;%path%
path %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%

:skip
REM carry on with additional code as needed
```

Comment: I like this solution best as it solves it in the plainest way, and you also answer the problem of integrating `setlocal` if needed. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo OFF
ECHO starting   %PATH%
if "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" CALL :addjava
ECHO.
ECHO resulting  %PATH%
GOTO :eof

:addjava
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
SET "path=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%"
GOTO :eof
```

This is what I'd use - other methods run afoul of the mininterpreted closing-parenthesis problem.

The key to understanding this odd behaviour is history. Batch has always substituted the parse-time value of any %var% into the code, then validated the result and executed if valid. As the language developed, it was necessary to maintain compatibility with existing batches, so you could only ADD new keywords and functionality, not remove or alter functionality.

So, as the capacity to call internal subroutines was added, and cascade instructions on a single line with `'&'` and allow multi-line instructions for `if` and `for` by enclosing the instructions in parentheses were introduced, and the capacity to use spaces and other separator characters in file or directory names was required, the batch language began to have a few little quirks.

It was a really bizarre decision to have the `!` to access the run-time value of a variable invoked as a subclause of `setlocal` - personally, I'd have used a switch like `ECHO on/off` (ie `EXPANSION on/off`) but I'm not running the project. In the same way, `DATE` could have been equipped with a `/u` switch to return the date in a universal form, but the opportunity was missed (and continues to be missed, 17 years after NT4 and 5 wingenerations later...)

Comment: I agree this is the right answer, i was personally not sure whether the original poster needed the extra vars or not. The problem is that the question header asks about escaping setlocal so that's what i set out to do.

Comment: I wrote my answer from my phone last night which I shouldn't have done since I couldn't test but it worked in my head. Obviously, I was wrong now that I've tested my code. I deleted it since it doesn't work. My next thought was to use a subroutine but you beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I'm going to give the accepted answer to dbenham but this one works perfectly too. It's still weird that multi-line `if` blocks behave this way -- since as you say they were an addition to the original syntax, it seems like they could have made the variable expansion delayed (done line-by-line) in the original implementation, no? But no matter.

Answer (score 3):

Everything inside the if block is evaluated in one go. So **%ANT_HOME%** has no effect after **set ANT_HOME**, you want delayed expansion you need to type:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%path:jdk1=%"=="%path%" (
    set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\ant
    set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
    path = !ANT_HOME!;!path!
    path = !JAVA_HOME!;!path!
)
:: important trick since they evaluate together %path% is still
:: what is inside local
endlocal & path %path%
path
```

Otherwise no delayed expansion. Also you need to use on undeleyed call with endlocal to escape the block. remember % variables never delay.

Comment: Is `!var!` really a thing? Trying that I just get `Path=!JAVA_HOME!\bin;!path!`

Comment: This works for the path now, but ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME are still trapped inside the setlocal. I need those too (or Ant does, apparently). When I tried moving the `endlocal` further up it went back to not understanding `!`. I'm lost.

Comment: in that case call a  subroutine like Peter Wright posts below. But obviously you can export more variables by putting more lines in the one evaluation block. My problem was that i was trying to preserve your design and answer your **subject line** instead of discarding it completely since you don't need setlocal to anything. Anyway to understand ! verus%

!var! expands at the time like  a real variable. 
%var% expends when the line is parsed since everything inside a paren () is one line it will not expand things you do inside the parens.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Even though it's not quite the right solution for me it solves the mystery of what I called the "bizarre" behavior -- I didn't know commands in parentheticals were parsed at once. The `&` trick was new to me too.